# dectect sifr is active on page

Tags: sifr, detect

I want to be able to check if sIFR has activated after the page has loaded so that I can then make other adjustments - sort of like setting up  () alternate behaviours

Since sIFR is already checking for the existence of flash, is there an easy global flag I can refer to, or should I just query the DOM to see if the sIFR-replaced class has been added ?

It would be more elgegant if you could just test on a flag ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With sIFR 3, you can check for `sIFR.isActive`.